# Saving images to a project folder in asp.net/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my method, I'm trying to save an image in a folder in the directory of my project. I have tried just putting the direct filepath of the folder, but that gives me an error when the project runs.

Is there a built-in extension of some kind in c# that would allow me to save this image in a folder in my directory; or way to simply access my directory without drilling to where my project is saved on my computer?

```
private void CreateBarcode()
{
    var bitmapImage = new Bitmap(500,300);
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapImage);

    g.Clear(Color.White);
    UPCbarcode barcode = new UPCbarcode(UPCbarcode.RandomGeneratedNumber(), bitmapImage, g);
    string filepath=@"images/image1.jpg";

    bitmapImage.Save(filepath,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Duplicate? [Saving a file in a specified folder inside my project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788217/saving-a-file-in-a-specified-folder-inside-my-project)

Comment: Try Server.MapPath ("images/"+filename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the AppData folder,

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "Image" folder is in the root directory of your Project use:

```
Server.MapPath("~/Image" + filename)
```

you can check if the file already exist at a location by :

```
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
     {
         // Your code to save the file
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that there is similarity in the name of the image file 
try putting it under a different name

like 
string filepath = @ "images / blabla or AI.jpg";

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

string filepath= Application.StartupPath + "\images\image1.jpg";

bitmapImage.Save(filepath,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);