# Getting path of file in current folder in Visual Studio and removing the bin/Debug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and am trying to get the name of the path of a file that is in the same folder in order to unit test.

So far I have used this code: 
`var directory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` which I hoped would get the base directory. However it returns the correct path WITH an extra: "\bin\Debug\netcoreap2.2" at the end, which I want to remove from the path.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding my project. I have tried deleting the files from the bin folder. However this does not work.

Does anyone know the solution for this please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the current project directory from C# code when creating a custom MSBuild task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816566/how-do-you-get-the-current-project-directory-from-c-sharp-code-when-creating-a-c)

Comment: Yes, thank you - I hadn't come across this one in my search @dns_nx  This solved my problem: 
`Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15653938/15060659

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative path and set "Copy to output" to "always" or "when newer" in the file properties. There's no reason your test code should go about searching for files in the other manner.